# TypeScript variable "implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation"

Tags: angular, typescript

Error:

> 'environment' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Code:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebaseConfig : {
        apiKey: "myKey",
        authDomain: "domain",
        projectId: "id",
        storageBucket: "storageUrl",
        messagingSenderId: "59142751602",
        appId: "a:b:web:c"
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below option in the tsconfig.json file:

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

Disabling the feature is not good idea but angular not allowed to run the project it shows error.

For more detailed explanation about [the "noImplicitAny" option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `any` type to the line `export const environment: any = { // details go here }`. The accepted answer works just fine, however, it will disable type checking across the whole project and being fair, what's the advantage of using Type Script?